# Given a positive int n, print “Has 1” if it contains a 1 digit otherwise print “Has No 1”

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    for(int i = n; i >= 0; i = n / 10)
    {   
        i = i % 10;

        if(i == 1)
            System.out.print("Has 1");

        n /= 10;
    }

    System.out.print("Has No 1");
}
```

It's working with "Has 1", but it's not printing anything when there is no digit 1. What's missing?

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of your current code won't do what you wish to achieve. Cause it is going in infinite loop (for both cases with 1 and not 1 numbers) because you are continuing the loop when `i >= 0` and `i` won't be negative for any positive numbers in the loop. Since the 1 case is within the loop, so it prints that statement.

Moreover, even if you correct the loop then it will still execute

```
System.out.print("Has No 1");
```

No matter if there is one in the given number or not.

You need to update this code to the following

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    boolean hasOne = false;
    int rem;

    for(int i = n; i > 0; i = i / 10)
    {   

       rem = i % 10;

        if(rem == 1)
            hasOne = true;
    }
    if(hasOne){
        System.out.println("Has 1");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Has No 1");
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A helper method makes it easy and reusable:

```
private static String hasDigit(int n, int digit) {
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 10)
        if (i % 10 == digit)
            return "Has " + digit;
    return "Has No " + digit;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(hasDigit(13579, 1));
System.out.println(hasDigit(24680, 1));
System.out.println(hasDigit(13579, 2));
System.out.println(hasDigit(24680, 2));
```

*Output*

```
Has 1
Has No 1
Has No 2
Has 2
```